# Javascript click event on Android mobile device browser doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a click event that works on desktop browser but not on my mobile I found a few similar threads but none helped to find a solution, this happens on Android haven't tried on other device. Thanks for input.

```
 const mobileMenuIcon = document.getElementById('mobile-menu-icon')

    mobileMenuIcon.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const mainMenu = document.getElementById('main-menu');

        if (mainMenu.classList.contains('hidden')){
            mainMenu.classList.replace('hidden', 'visible');
        } else {
            mainMenu.classList.replace('visible', 'hidden');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe it’s related to how the button is displayed, did you debugged it with the mobile plugged to the desktop inspector?

Comment: Does this happen strictly on iOS?

Comment: Removed the `mobile` tag as it refers to something totally different than mobile development. Please add the relevant explicit tag to your questions instead, iOS, Android, etc.. and make sure to read the tag's text to ensure you are adding the tags you intend to add.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is the event triggered but your event handler code is producing errors or is your click event even triggered? Add a `console.log('xxxx')` at the top of your event handler to see if it is triggered to begin with. Also, please read the [**classList Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to check if your mobile browser is supported for the functions you are using. `replace()` doesn't seem to be in a lot of them but you should have seen that as an error potentially...

Comment: @nope you're right, there's no support for replace on Android mobile Thanks I didn't know I could check that new kid on the js block, sorry.